# Using autofill in Javafx

Tags: webview, javafx-2, javafx

I am trying to use Javafx webviewer to display a page and embed it in a webpage (since the page breaks iframe), and I need to have autofill on the page, is there a way to do this? I tried googling but didn't return any result.

Comment: Duplicate of: [Fill fields WebView in Java automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038369/fill-fields-webview-in-java-automatically).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution to my own questions,
ended up manually writing a macro that use keypress to input data, and make it trigger on mousseclicks.
its not ideal but it works.