# Fill fields WebView in Java automatically

Tags: java, swing, webview, javafx, field

So here's my problem. I'm using WebView class from JavaFX in swing. The thing I want to do is that I want fields loaded in webview to be filled automatically with information stored in an array. Is it possible?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I would say it might not be impossible. Take a look at the WebEngine documentation. You need to update the document elements...

Comment: Can you please show a simple Example, Thanks

Comment: I'm not actualy farmiluar with FX, but if, you have a read of the [`WebEngine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html), you will see an example where they access the DOC to add a event trigger, this might give an entry point into figuring out how to set the field text...

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer, just one more question. Maybe it's available to run a javascript to fill fields? It seems to be way more easier way.

Comment: Can't say, `WebEngine` does seem to provide some kind access into the javascript engine, but you'd have to read up on it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed this with JavaFX webView Javascript engine.
If anyone is intersted here's code snippet.

```
    String setLastName  =  "document.getElementsByName('lastName')[0].value='" + lastName + "';";
    String setName =  "document.getElementsByName('firstName')[0].value='" + name + "'";
    String setDateBirth = "document.getElementsByName('birthdate')[0].value='" + datebirth + "';";
    String setPhone = "document.getElementsByName('phone')[0].value='" + phone + "';";
    String setEmail = "document.getElementsByName('email')[0].value='" + email + "';";
    String setPassport = "document.getElementsByName('passport')[0].value='" + passport + "';";
    Button button = new Button("Fill the form");

    button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            webEngine.executeScript(setLastName);
            webEngine.executeScript(setName);
            webEngine.executeScript(setDateBirth);
            webEngine.executeScript(setPhone);
            webEngine.executeScript(setEmail);
            webEngine.executeScript(setPassport);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is an automated form fill example JavaFX app for WebView.

Values (login credentials) are entered into JavaFX fields in the yellow part of the screen and then automatically posted (using the w3c dom api) in the WebView (the white part of the screen) when the login page appears.

[image: loginpost]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.beans.value.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.web.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.w3c.dom.html.*;

public class WebViewFormPost extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final TextField fxUsername = new TextField();
        fxUsername.setPrefColumnCount(20);
        final TextField fxPassword = new PasswordField();

        final BooleanProperty loginAttempted = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

        final WebView webView = new WebView();
        webView.setPrefWidth(1000);
        final WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
        engine.documentProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Document>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Document> ov, Document oldDoc, Document doc) {
                if (doc != null && !loginAttempted.get()) {
                    if (doc.getElementsByTagName("form").getLength() > 0) {
                        HTMLFormElement form = (HTMLFormElement) doc.getElementsByTagName("form").item(0);
                        if ("/oam/server/sso/auth_cred_submit".equals(form.getAttribute("action"))) {
                            HTMLInputElement username = null;
                            HTMLInputElement password = null;
                            NodeList nodes = form.getElementsByTagName("input");
                            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                                HTMLInputElement input = (HTMLInputElement) nodes.item(i);
                                switch (input.getName()) {
                                    case "ssousername":
                                        username = input;
                                        break;
                                    case "password":
                                        password = input;
                                        break;
                                }
                            }

                            if (username != null && password != null) {
                                loginAttempted.set(true);
                                username.setValue(fxUsername.getText());
                                password.setValue(fxPassword.getText());
                                form.submit();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        engine.getLoadWorker().exceptionProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Throwable>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Throwable> ov, Throwable oldException, Throwable exception) {
                System.out.println("Load Exception: " + exception);
            }
        });

        GridPane inputGrid = new GridPane();
        inputGrid.setHgap(10);
        inputGrid.setVgap(10);
        inputGrid.addRow(0, new Label("Username: "), fxUsername);
        inputGrid.addRow(0, new Label("Password: "), fxPassword);

        Button fxLoginButton = new Button("Login to Oracle Forums");
        fxLoginButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                if (notEmpty(fxPassword.getText()) && notEmpty(fxPassword.getText())) {
                    loginAttempted.set(false);
                    engine.load("https://forums.oracle.com/community/developer/english/java/javafx/login.jspa");
                }
            }
        });
        fxLoginButton.setDefaultButton(true);
        ProgressIndicator fxLoadProgress = new ProgressIndicator(0);
        fxLoadProgress.progressProperty().bind(webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().progressProperty());
        fxLoadProgress.visibleProperty().bind(webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().runningProperty());

        HBox loginPane = new HBox(10);
        loginPane.getChildren().setAll(
                fxLoginButton,
                fxLoadProgress
        );

        final VBox layout = new VBox(10);
        layout.setStyle("-fx-background-color: cornsilk; -fx-padding: 10;");
        layout.getChildren().addAll(
                new Label("Enter your Oracle Web Account credentials"),
                inputGrid,
                loginPane,
                webView
        );
        VBox.setVgrow(webView, Priority.ALWAYS);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();

        fxUsername.requestFocus();
    }

    private boolean notEmpty(String s) {
        return s != null && !"".equals(s);
    }
}
```

The above application is adapted from a previous Oracle forum question on [Submitting HTML Forms with JavaFX Webview](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2510161).

If you don't have an Oracle technology network account to test the above program, you can sign up for one here: https://myprofile.oracle.com/EndUser/faces/profile/createUser.jspx.

*Posting to WebView using JQuery*

An alternate implementation, that I would actually prefer is to use is JavaScript [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to introspect the DOM and perform the post rather than using the Java DOM apis.  There is a sample for using [jQuery on any arbitrary webpage hosted in a WebView](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/3077942).  So you could combine the ideas from this automated WebView form post and the jQuery hosted WebView sample to create a version which uses JQuery to perform the post.